# Sequelize,проблема с подзапросом,рейтинг и продукты

Tags: sequelize.js

Есть код.
То что я хочу получить: список товаров,сортированных по количеству,средний рейтинг,количество оценок.
В итоге этим кодом я получаю только ОДИН товар.

```
Product.findAll({
      offset,
      limit: 15,
      order: [["amount", "desc"]],
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Rating,
          attributes: [
            [
              sequelize.fn("avg", sequelize.col("ratingValue")),
              "averageRating"
            ],
            [
              sequelize.fn("count", sequelize.col("ratingValue")),
              "amountOfRatings"
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }).then(products => products));
```

Как только убираю:

```
 include: [
            {
              model: models.Rating,
              attributes: [
                [
                  sequelize.fn("avg", sequelize.col("ratingValue")),
                  "averageRating"
                ],
                [
                  sequelize.fn("count", sequelize.col("ratingValue")),
                  "amountOfRatings"
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
```

Получаю всё как надо,только без рейтинга -_-. 
ссылка на весь проект: https://github.com/Deeathwiing/VSTU-LAB-SERVER-EXPRESS
Спасибо за ответы

Comment: Типа, используя три буквы на латинице, люди не поймут о какой части тела идёт речь?

Answer (score 0):

Вот например

```
   let smt_db=await models.City.findAll({
        order: [
            ['id', 'ASC']
        ],
        attributes: ['id','Name'],
        include: [{
            model: models.Generation,

            attributes: ["CityId",
                [
                    models.sequelize.fn("count", models.sequelize.col("TemplateId")),
                    "TemplateIdCnt1"
                ],
                [
                    models.sequelize.fn("count", models.sequelize.col("TemplateId")),
                    "TemplateIdCnt2"
                ]
            ],

            group: ["CityId"],

        }],
        raw:true,
        group: ["City.Name","City.id","Generations.CityId"]
    }).then((Items) => {
        return Items;
    });
```

Тут те же принципы что и в SQL. Сгруппировал по ID и нашел все агрегирующие метрики. Главное raw:true поставить, чтобы не выносились в запрос первичные ключи.

Comment: Если бы всё так было просто,вот результат: 
https://imgur.com/a/nt4ePyh

Comment: я пробовал 100500 различных комбинаций,ничего не получается. Нагуглил только то,что это невозможно сделать только исп ORM,нужно еще и raw запрос писать через sequelize.leteral()

Comment: Спасибо,но это также не работает.
https://imgur.com/a/pbaCiPD

Comment: Так как у вас запрос написан не будет работать.**Только** агрегируемые атрибуты нужно оставить. В примере внимательно посмотрите какие поля выводятся.

Comment: У меня нету промежуточной таблицы,есть только Ratings,Products, Users(в данном случае не исп). 
Вот сделал в точности как вы говорите: https://imgur.com/a/NmBRJqR . 
Можете сказать что надо просто исправить на что

Comment: если удаляю "ratings.productId",то ошибки нет,но приходит только 1 товар,в котором: ratings.productId(pin):1
ratings.averageRating(pin):"2.8333"
ratings.amountOfRatings(pin):6

Comment: при этом это общий рейтинг ВСЕХ товаров и количество оценок ВСЕХ товаров,а не для каждого товара отдельно.

Comment: Проблема решилась обычным добавлением subQuery: false,
Я делал всё правильно.)